# Starling: laying out the assets inside Adobe Flash IDE

Tags: performance, flash, layout, air

I just want to know if I could have the best of both worlds:

- Performance of Starling.
- Simplicity of the Flash IDE placing the graphic elements by dragging them with the mouse (and not by their X and Y properties in the code).

I know you can convert MovieClips into working textures for Starling (by the third party utility DynamicAtlas), but I need to preserve all the Layout and nesting of the movies inside a MovieClip container.

So does exist a utility or something that can do that? (without loosing perceptive performance?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an extension library that do the trick:
http://www.xtdstudios.com/dmt.html
It's in alpha stage but worked good for me. It has no wiki, tutorial or comments, only a demo. But I think it has a good future.